What is the P&L
I have a question about the P&L calculation, please.
If we sell a call option on a stock with a volatility of 16%. Theta is worth 100€/day. Let's assume that the spot moves by 2% in one day. What is the P&L ?
Thank you for the help

Can’t be calculated precisely from the information given, but we can make an approximation:
-first, assume that you delta hedged your call so we start with a delta neutral portfolio
-second, note that 16% vol is equivalent to a daily move of 16%/sqrt(252)= about 1% per day

we may therefore estimate that a move of 1% would balance the negative gamma versus the theta.  Hence , the negative gamma p/l of a 1% move is -100.
Since gamma is quadratic, the gamma p/l of a 2% move should be -400.
Hence the overall p/l = theta gain minus gamma loss = 100-400= a loss of 300 dollars.


Thank for your answer !
Why can u suppose that a move of 1% would balance the negative gamma versus the theta ? I don't see why this assumption would be logical or narutal ?

The fundamental equation of option pricing, aka the Black Scholes equation, basically says that time decay equals Expected gamma p/l.   The move of 1% daily is the expected move, given that the option is priced at 16% annual volatility.

I’m being rather loose with the details, apologies to the quants

Thank you !
One more question, i don't understand where do we use that the vol is 1% per day ? And why did you choose to work with gamma instead of, for example, vega?

We use that the gamma p/l of a 1% move is 100k, in order to calculate the gamma p/l of a 2% move.   Second question we assumed implied vol did not move so there is no Vega p/l.  Pls consult a basic options text.

Thank you for your responses. It is difficult to find information on the internet about this, so your advice is not very useful.
